# How to inject a file into a Linux VM running on Hyper-V?

Tags: linux, powershell, hyper-v, ext4, vhd

I am trying to create a CentOS image template and my environment requires me to add a route file to the networking which would be different on each deployment.

Is there any way for me to inject a file from a Hyper-V host to a ext4 formatted Linux guest VHD?

Ideally I'd like to be able to write to script the creation of a VM in Powershell by copying the template VHD and injecting the route file to the VHD.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to perform this.

If you have [Linux Integration Services (LIS)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55106) installed, you can use the [`Copy-VMFile` Cmdlet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/copy-vmfile) on the Hyper-V host where the VM is running to copy the files into the Linux VM. On the VM settings, you need to [enable Guest Services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/manage/manage-hyper-v-integration-services).

Once you have the LIS installed in Linux guest and Guest Services enabled in VM settings, ensure that the `hypervfcopyd` is running inside the guest. You can, then, use the `Copy-VMFile` cmdlet.

```
Copy-VMFile -Name centos001n -SourcePath 'C:\Scripts\myPytonLib.tar' -DestinationPath '/home/ravi/scripts' -FileSource Host
```

There are, of course, other methods if you have network connectivity.